# BackgroundWorker freezes UI when using Invoke, reporting progress

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I read both [BackgroundWorker still freezes UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22205015/backgroundworker-still-freezes-ui) and [UI still freezes using backgroundWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526356/ui-still-freezes-using-backgroundworker) but neither have helped me solve my issue. I asked a question a few days ago about [Datatable not displaying information after SQL query fill in backgroundworker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55331467/datatable-not-displaying-information-after-sql-query-fill-in-backgroundworker), which I eventually solved by using `Invoke` and a `delegate`.

My current code (shown below) gives me the results I want, except for two things: it doesn't actually display the progress bar (at least that I can see) and it freezes the UI while running:

```
DataTable tab1table = new DataTable();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Instantiatesearch1Thread();
}

private void Instantiatesearch1Thread()
{
    search1Thread.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    search1Thread.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    search1Thread.ProgressChanged += search1Thread_ProgressChanged;
    search1Thread.DoWork += search1Thread_Dowrk;
    search1Thread.RunWorkerCompleted += search1Thread_RunWorkerCompleted;
}

    private void sbutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    search1Thread.RunWorkerAsync();
}
void search1Thread_Dowrk(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int percentprogress = 0;
        var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        // Ensure process is thread-safe by using Invoke method
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            // Search1 button event handler
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connection_Info))
        {

            conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter(comboBox1SQL, conn))
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("Working");
                    if (comboBox1.Text.Contains("ID"))
                    {
                        long para = long.Parse(search1.Text);
                        cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
                        {
                            ParameterName = "@combo1Par",
                            Value = para,
                            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.BigInt
                        });
                    }

                    // Clear datatable if it contains any information and then fill it
                    if (tab1table != null)
                        tab1table.Clear();
                    cmd.Fill(tab1table);

                    // Set Progress Bar info
                    search1Progress.Maximum = tab1table.Rows.Count;
                    groupBox2.Controls.Add(search1Progress);
                    search1Progress.BringToFront();
                }                   

        }

            // This is a long calculation where I am reporting the 
            // progress every iteration (which is probably not helping,
            // but didn't change anything when commented out).

            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search1.Text) && tab1Combo1.SelectedIndex > -1 || tab1Combo2.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                for (int i = tab1table.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    DataRow dr = tab1table.Rows[i];
                    if (!dr.ItemArray.Contains(search1.Text.ToString()))
                    {
                        dr.Delete();
                        tab1table.AcceptChanges();
                    }
                    percentprogress++;
                    worker.ReportProgress(percentprogress);
                }
            }
        }));
}

void search1Thread_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    search1Progress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

void search1Thread_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
                tab1datatable.DataSource = null;
        tab1datatable.DataSource = tab1table;
        tab1datatable.Update();
        groupBox2.Controls.Remove(search1Progress);
        MessageBox.Show(" Your search returned " + tab1table.Rows.Count.ToString() + " results");
}
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

My issue may have something to do with `Invoke` as I know it's not the best method with `BackgroundWorker`, but I couldn't get it to update the UI using any other method.

Comment: You must stop using Invoke().  Right now that background worker doesn't do any work at all in the background, everything runs on the UI thread.  So it blocks the UI.  That probably happened because you used comboBox1, you need to pass any data that the worker needs as an argument to RunWorkerSync().  That could be a SqlCommand by the looks of it.

Comment: @HansPassant used `search1Thread.RunWorkerAsync(comboBox1SQL);` but then I get no results. Is it unable to access the values in the comboBoxes and textBoxes? If so, how do I send those arguments to it?

Comment: You can pass an **object** to `DoWork()`. Meaning, you can pass a composite class object that contains multiple informations. The informations you need in the `DoWork` method. The `ComboBox.Text`, for example. Or any other thing.

Comment: @HansPassant So I need to create a composite class object that contains all the variables from the comboboxes and textboxes, as well as any strings (SQL command) or anything else from the UI thread I may need? And then running `RunWorkerCompleted` will automatically pass what is needed to the UI (in this case the filled `DataTable`? Would it be possible for you to show an example of that?

Comment: There are simple examples in [How to: Run an Operation in the Background](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-run-an-operation-in-the-background?view=netframework-4.7.2) of both passing in parameters, and passing out a result with the BackgroundWorker control.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Do i need to pass the Datatable, as well? since it's being output to the UI?

Comment: No.  You need to update the UI w/ the DataTable info from the UI thread, but you don't need to pass it directly in those events (unless it's not accessible otherwise).

Comment: @Idle_Mind It is accessible anywhere in the UI (see the first line in the code above).